# Laravel @guest can't identify one of custom guards

Tags: laravel

Laravel (5.8) @guest can't identify one of custom guards. I have 2 custom guards:

```
'guards' => [
        'suppliers' => [
            'driver'  => 'session',
            'provider' => 'suppliers',
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver'  => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
],

'providers' => [
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'suppliers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Supplier::class,
        ],
],
```

Login routes are:

```
// Admin Auth routes
Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login.post');
Route::post('/admin/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

// Suppliers Auth routes
Route::get('/login', 'AuthSuppliers\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'AuthSuppliers\LoginController@login')->name('login.post');
Route::post('/logout', 'AuthSuppliers\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

Everythink works fine with `suppliers` but `admins` can't be identified as logged in with blade @guest directive, however `Auth::guard('admins')->check()` returning true.

The quest is more like: how to use blade with multiple guards. For example how can I print user name if I don't know which guard exactly logged in?

Comment: Auth::user() always give logged in user information. you can try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the laravel docs:

> If needed, you may specify the authentication guard that should be checked
> when using the @auth and @guest directives:
>
> ```
> @auth('admin')
>      // The user is authenticated...
> @endauth
>
> @guest('admin')
>     // The user is not authenticated...
> @endguest
> ```

So you can give `@auth` and `@guest` a parameter that is the authentication guard used for the check

Comment: Ok what about @guest('suppliers') ? It will output content if you logged in as admin, this will not work, I made helper for this task, can't see other way.

Comment: You can use multiple nested guest:  `@guest('suppliers) @guest('admins) ... @endguest @endguest`